# PHP not parsing query result corectly

Tags: php, mysql, sybase

When I run some PHP code I run into errors which I cant explain. I'm running a query from PHP.

> Warning: sybase_query() [function.sybase-query]: Sybase: Server
>   message: Incorrect syntax near '='. (severity 15, procedure N/A) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wil\Testen\ZKO-backend\php\ui_table.php on line 20

and:

> Warning: sybase_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wil\Testen\ZKO-backend\php\ui_table.php on line 21

The query which is called runs perfectly in Sybase and the same routine runs perfectly on similar queries

I get the errors for every record the query delivers, so I think the problem should be in the PHP code which is not able to handle the output of the query.

Query:

```
<?PHP
$subquery= "SELECT distinct
ds_u_in.DATASET_ID,
 ds_u_in.USED_INSTRUMENT_ID,
 '<td>' + inv_in_type.NAME +'</td>' AS LONG_TABLEROW,
 '<td>' + per_org_man.NAME +'</td>' AS LONG_TABLEROW2,
 '<td>' + inv_in.SERIAL +'</td>' AS LONG_TABLEROW3,
 '<td>' + per_org.NAME +'</td>' AS LONG_TABLEROW4,
 '<td>' + inv_in.DEPARTMENT +'</td>' AS LONG_TABLEROW5

FROM 
 dataset..DATASET_USED_INSTRUMENT ds_u_in,
 inventory..USED_INSTRUMENT inv_u_in,
 inventory..INSTRUMENT_TYPE inv_in_type,
 inventory..INSTRUMENT inv_in,
 person..ORGANISATION per_org_man,
 person..ORGANISATION per_org

WHERE ds_u_in.USED_INSTRUMENT_ID = inv_u_in.USED_INSTRUMENT_ID
  AND inv_u_in.INSTRUMENT_TYPE_ID = inv_in_type.INSTRUMENT_TYPE_ID
  AND inv_u_in.INSTRUMENT_ID *= inv_in.INSTRUMENT_ID
  AND per_org_man.ORGANISATION_ID =* inv_in_type.MANUFACTURER_ORGANISATION_ID
  AND per_org.ORGANISATION_ID =* inv_in.ORGANISATION_ID
  AND ds_u_in.USED_INSTRUMENT_ID = {K} ";
?>
```

The {K} is replaced by an integer before executing the query.

Php code to show the result:

```
            for ($k = 1; $k <= $_SESSION[$name]; $k++) {
            $mysubquery=sybase_query(str_replace('{K}',$_SESSION[$name.'_'.$k],$subquery));
            $subrow = sybase_fetch_array($mysubquery);
            if ($subrow)  { 
                if (isset($subrow["LONG_TABLEROW"])) {
                    if(strlen($subrow["LONG_TABLEROW"]) >=1) {
                        echo "<tr>".$subrow["LONG_TABLEROW"];
                        for ($l = 2; $l <= 9; $l++) {
                            if (isset($subrow["LONG_TABLEROW".$l])) {
                                if (strlen($subrow["LONG_TABLEROW".$l]) >=1) {
                                    echo $subrow["LONG_TABLEROW".$l];
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                }
                echo '<td><img onclick="javascript:DeleteLine())" src="images/trash.png" /> ';
                if ($k == $_SESSION[$name] ) { 
                    echo 'add' ;
                }
                echo '</td></tr>';
            }
        }
```

Is someone seeing what is going wrong here?

Comment: looks like your query failed and return false

Comment: Are you using the correct database? Did you select a database when you set up the connection? It does needs to know in which database to search for tables and such. Usually a `use databasename` suffices?  what does var_dump($subrow) yield?

Comment: var_dump gives no output, just a extra error:Warning: sybase_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wil\Testen\ZKO-backend\php\ui_table.php on line 19

Comment: Found the error!  The variable {k} is set to blank.The problem must be in a totally different part of the code.